# WTSQuerySessionInformation not working with .NET EXE

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a legacy program meant to test the terminal sessions to see if a particular user is logged in or not and to send a mail if that user is not logged in. Coding has been done with using calls to `WTSQuerySessionInformation` as follows

```
        If WTSQuerySessionInformationW(ptrOpenedServer, active_session, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, str, returned) = True Then
            ClientInfo.WTSUserName = str
            riter.AppendLine("feeded UserName" + str + " Active sessin: " + active_session.ToString() + " returned :" + returned.ToString())
        Else
            riter.AppendLine("Failed in feeding UserName")
        End If

    'Get StationName of this TS session
        If WTSQuerySessionInformationW(ptrOpenedServer, active_session, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSWinStationName, str, returned) = True Then
            ClientInfo.WTSStationName = str
            riter.AppendLine("feeded StationName" + str + " Active sessin: " + active_session.ToString() + " returned :" + returned.ToString())
        Else
            riter.AppendLine("Failed in feeding StationName")
        End If

    'Get Domain Name of this TS session
        If WTSQuerySessionInformationW(ptrOpenedServer, active_session, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSDomainName, str, returned) = True Then
            ClientInfo.WTSDomainName = str
            riter.AppendLine("feeded Domain" + str + " Active sessin: " + active_session.ToString() + " returned :" + returned.ToString())
        Else

            riter.AppendLine("Failed in feeding Domain")
        End If
```

The above program is running fine on Windows 2003 but its not running on Windows 7/Windows 2008 R2. When I tried to debug the code its running fine but when I deploy the program as scheduled task its not running and the function `WTSQuerySessionInformation` is giving empty details for username... etc.

So would like to know if I'm missing anything for Win 7/2008 R2.

Comment: There is strong evidence that you are using a bad pinvoke declaration for WTSQuerySessionInformationW().  The 4th argument must be a StringBuilder that's initialized with a sufficient Capacity.  Right now you are probably mutating an immutable string and corrupting the GC heap.  Anything can go wrong after that.

Comment: I tried redeclarign string everytime in every call to that method but still the same response.